# Using C# with Active Directory Tutorials

Tags: c#, active-directory

Can anyone suggest some tutorials for beginners that utilize the C# language to access Active Directory? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at this [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx) and this [MSDN code sample collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180833.aspx). The [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) is actually really simple - the hard part is finding the desired information in the directory. From my (limited) experience the (naming) schema of the standard ActiveDirectory is not that consistent. [Active Directory Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx) might be very helpful at this point.

Comment: That CodeProject article is pretty much a mini-Bible on AD for C# developers!

Comment: big thumbs up for the Active Directory Explorer - many thanks!

Comment: code project article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C